# Counting the amount of digits in a while loop does not work

Tags: c

I use the following code to count the amount of digits in a while loop, so "0" should be 1, "10" should be 2 etc. - however the code does not seem to work. Can you please help me?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 
 int main()
 {
     int x;
     int division;
     int counter=0;
     
     printf("Enter a number : ");
     scanf("%d",&x); 

     do
     {
         division=x/10;
         counter++;
     }
     while(division!=0);
     printf("This number contains : %d digits",counter);
     
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Niether `x` or `10` ever change.  Why would you expect `division` to change?

Answer (score 1):

please change  `division=x/10;` to `x /= 10` and corresponding while condition. x is not changed your code, thus you get stucked in you while loop forever

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
division = x / 10;
```

Will be performed forever since the condition given in the `while` logic never becomes false.

**If you do:**

```
do {
    x = x / 10;
    counter++;
} while (x != 0);
```

It'll work.

---

**Enhanced version of your code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    int counter = 0;

    printf("Enter a number : ");

    // looping until a correct format is provided
    while (scanf("%d", &x) == 0) {
        printf("Incorrect values, enter again: ");
        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    }

    do {
        x = x / 10;
        counter++;
    } while (x != 0);

    printf("This number contains : %d digits.", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

The intention behind the "enhanced version" is to verify if the input is correctly given as formatted in coding (i.e. accepting an integer and nothing else) which isn't in your program.

Also, you don't need to include `stdlib.h` for your own code. That works without it too.

**You'll then get the following sample output:**

```
Enter a number : asdlfjal;sdk
Incorrect values, enter again:  asdf sdf 
Incorrect values, enter again: 33334
This number contains : 5 digits.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the division value. This should work

```c
#include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 
 int main()
 {
     int x;
     int division;
     int counter=0;
     
     printf("Enter a number : ");
     scanf("%d",&x); 
     do
        {
            x=x/10;
            counter++;
        }
        while(x!=0);
        printf("This number contains : %d digits",counter);
        
        return 0;
    }
```